# How to spark count() faster for huge dataframes?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have data pipeline operator used to collect metrics of the data.
The data product for which I am collecting metrics is called `foo`

I have the following

```
`foo.select(foo.id).count()` => 2M+
`foo.filter(foo.id.startswith("foobar")).count() => 1M
```

I do a bunch of other operations(count and collect)
The `count()` take a very long time :( (around 30minutes)

How do folks usually solve problems of this nature? 
Also, I do not care about the exact `count`. I need an approx(+-50,000)

I have also tried `countApprox` but there is no change in the amount of time taken

Config

```
Number of cores = 150
driver-memory = 15g
executory-memory = 15g
```

Comment: @user6910411 - this is not a duplicate of it. am I missing something?

Comment: If you want to count it multiple times and you don't want to wait. You can do `foo.cache()`. This is only when you are testing. Do NOT do this on real data. Because, all the data is loaded into driver.

Comment: It's essential that you should provide these following info :
+ your Foo class's definition 
+ where did you read/construct the dataframe: 'foo' from?

Comment: @supritashankar You want to improve performance, right? Then, instead of using `.filter > .count` apply a single aggregation processing all conditions (expressed as `CASE ... WHEN` expressions) at once.